# 'bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 5' in Node

Tags: postgresql, post, postman, massive

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my POST is not working using Nodejs and Massivejs. I am trying to add a test product using Postman and it's giving me the **"bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 5"** error. I think it has to do with the SQL file having 5 variables, but my image of postman shows 5 key value pairs which I would think would set those variables from the req.body.

I'm clearly missing something. Any ideas?

server.js

```
app.post("/api/products", function(req, res, next){
 const newProduct = req.body;
  db.add_product(newProduct, function(err, product){
   if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send(err)
   }
  return res.status(200).send(newProduct) 
 })
});
```

add_product.sql

```
INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, img1, img2)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);
```

[postman image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2rCb.png)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
let query: string = `INSERT INTO users(handle, firstname, lastname,
            email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`;     
await pool.query(query, [handle, firstname, lastname, email, password]);
```